# MOSFET small signal model question

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, gain, small-signal

Why is v<sub>gs</sub> = v<sub>in</sub> - v<sub>out</sub> as stated in the image?

The book has g<sub>m</sub>v<sub>GS</sub> wrong as it's supposed to be a current source.

[image: MOSFET]

Comment: What answer do you expect from us?